# jQuery iframe access working only the first time in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox, iframe

I am using jQuery and Ruby On Rails.
I have an ajax call `$.get()` which renders a piece of html containing a iframe

I want to modify the iframe in order to make sure the `<a>` links open in a new window.

To do this I have added an onload to the iframe definition:

```
<iframe id="iframe_message_<%= message.id %>" class="iframe_message" name ="iframe_message_<%=  message.id %>" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="<%= message.attachments.body_html.first.document.url %>"  onLoad="autoResize('iframe_message_<%= message.id %>');">
```

the `autoResize` function is defined in the html rendered by the ajax call and contains:

```
$(".iframe_message").ready(function () { 
    $('a', frames[id].document).attr('target','_blank');
});
```

This works fine in IE, Safari but I have a problem with firefox where it works the first time the `$.get()` is called by a mouse click but not on the following click (the `<a>` tags are not modified).

I thought on a caching issue and replaced the `$.get()` by the `$.ajax()` with `cache:true` but I still have the same behaviour.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went of the jQuery website and looked at the [.content](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) description
and my "working" code is

```
$("#"+id).contents().find("a").attr('target','_blank');
```

where `"#"+id` is the id of my iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your description, but your jquery may need to be called from within the iframe. Think of the iframe as a separate web page.

Comment: Hello thanks for you answer. I have not access to the iFrame until it is loaded on my page so I can't put javascript in it. And in addition this work for different browser except Firefox

Comment: I have done further testing and the weird thing is that, with firefox at the first call all my links in the iframe are modified with a target="_blank", and when I click the second time it modifies all the lin outside the iframe and not the iframe.